# Programmatically disable editing on named ranges in google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, permissions, range, google-sheets

Does anyone know how to programmatically assign shared users with 'VIEW' permission on a named range in javascript for google spreadsheet? I can do it thru context menu, but haven't found how to accomplish in javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

protection of named ranges is not currently supported by Google-spreadsheet-api. This [Feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1721) asks for this. You may want to star it to keep track of updates and kind of vote for it.